# Calculate position of a point on an arc

Tags: math, graphics

I'm building a gauge. I took off from an example that was a half circle, see from the image:
[image: Original version]

To transform percentage into the angle the original chart had these three functions:

```
percToDeg: function (perc) {
        return perc * 360;
      },
percToRad: function (perc) {
        return this.degToRad(this.percToDeg(perc));
      },

degToRad: function (deg) {
        return deg * Math.PI / 180;
      },
```

Now this all looks and works great, however I wanted to adjust the gauge so that the arc extends another 45 degrees in both directions, see this:

[image: Desired gauge]

However now percToDeg function doesn't work anymore. Can you please help me figure out a function that for a given percentage places the point (tip of the needle in my case) of on the arc correctly - 0% should be 225 degrees, 50% 90 degrees and 100% -45 degrees?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to ask it here? https://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use something called [linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation), with your starting range being [0, 100] and your destination range being [225, -45].

The general equation for this, for an x in range [a, b] to y in range [c, d]

```
y = c + (x - a) * (d - c) / (b - a)
```

In your case,

```
a = 0
b = 100
c = 225
d = -45
```

For example, if you want to find where 50 maps to in the range:

```
y = 225 + (50 - 0) * (-45 - 225) / (100 - 0)
y = 225 + 50 * -270 / 100
y = 225 - 135
y = 90
```

Comment: Funnily, I'm using lerp in different place in the code. I just thought this has some other, goniometric solution :)